# How do i fix low storage space so i don't have to reset my phone?

Tags: internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory, samsung-intercept

I have an android Samsung Intercept SPH-M910 and I have read all the directions for resetting and clearing apps and cache. However I still have to reset my phone every three days because the low storage error comes back because what I have cleared out doesn't seem to really clear.

I have gone to settings and then applications, but there is no storage space after that... it is however after settings but does not let me change anything it just shows how much is available. How can I get my internal storage back to normal?

Comment: Which steps exactly have you performed? If just clearing cache, that won't be enough for long (as it re-fills). Your device only ships with 512 MB storage altogether, part of that certainly being reserved for the OS; so I'm afraid you'll have to sort out some apps to avoid the "low storage" problem.

Answer (score -1):

move the big application installed in the internal memory to sd card and clear cache .. with some appz like ccleaner for android..

Comment: CCleaner for Android hasn't been released, to my knowledge. If it has, then a link to the app would be helpful.